# Numerical Integration through Plotting

Tags: code-golf, calculus

Inspired by this on Spiked Math:

[image]
<sub>(source: [spikedmath.com](http://spikedmath.com/comics/357-numerical-integration.png))</sub>

In this code golf, you are going to write a numerical integrator. Instead of weighting, you first plot on a graphic canvas pixel-by-pixel or plot on a 2D array, then calculate the integral by counting the colored pixels.

You are implementing a function with the following arguments:

- `f`: the function, in lambda or function pointer
- `xmin`, `xmax`: the interval, also the familiar window settings on a typical graphic calculator
- `ymin`, `ymax`: window settings for y-axis, note: it is the caller's responsibility to choose ymax, because the function can go over ymax, and the parts went over will not be counted.
- `xres`, `yres`: resolution of the plot: size of the canvas or the dimensions of the 2D array

Here is an explanation:

To integrate `sin(x)` from 1.0 to 8.0 with y = -1.0 to 1.0, and resolution 30 * 15, first plot

```
 ++++                       ++
++++++                     +++
+++++++                   ++++
++++++++                 +++++
++++++++                 +++++
+++++++++               ++++++
+++++++++              +++++++
          -------------       
           -----------        
           -----------        
            ---------         
            --------          
             -------          
              -----
```

Count the total number of `+`s: 83
total number of `-`s: 64
and N = 83 - 64 = 19

(the formula for N is actually
[image: formula]
notice `xres-1`, x never equal to `xres`, don't make this off-by-one error
)

and calculate the integral:

```
N / canvas size * window area
= (N / (xres * yres) ) * ((ymax - ymin) * (xmax - xmin))
= 19 / (30 * 15) * ((1 - (-1)) * (8 - 1))
~= 0.5911
```

Shortest code wins.

Test cases:

```
| f(x)       |  xmin |  xmax |  ymin | ymax  | xres | yres | S f(x) dx |
| 3          |  0.0  |  10.0 |   0.0 |   2.0 |   25 |   25 |  20.0     |
| 3          |  0.0  |  10.0 |   0.0 |   5.0 |    5 |    5 |  30.0     |
| 3          |  0.0  |  10.0 |   0.0 |   4.0 |    5 |    5 |  32.0     |
| 2x + 2     | -5.0  |   5.0 | -10.0 |  10.0 |   50 |   50 |  18.72    |
| 2x + 2     | -5.0  |   5.0 | -20.0 |  20.0 |  500 |  500 |  20.1648  |
| x^2        |  0.0  |  10.0 |   0.0 | 120.0 |   10 |   10 | 348.0     |
| x^2        |  0.0  |  10.0 |   0.0 | 120.0 |  100 |  100 | 335.88    |
| x^2        |  0.0  |  10.0 |   0.0 | 120.0 |  500 |  500 | 333.6768  |
| x^2 sin(x) | -3.14 |  3.14 |  -5.0 |   5.0 |   50 |   50 |   0.60288 |
| x^2 sin(x) | -3.14 |  3.14 |  -5.0 |   5.0 | 1500 | 1500 |   0.60288 |
| sin(x^2)   |  0.0  | 10.0  |  -1.0 |   1.0 |  250 |   50 |   0.7808  |
| sin(x^2)   |  0.0  | 10.0  |  -1.0 |   1.0 | 1000 | 1000 |   0.59628 |
```

Comment: This is not well specified. Will the function be supplied as a function argument? Or is the code supposed to parse some expression syntax? Is the aim a function, or a program that takes text input and output? Does the code need to actually plot into a 2D array, or just calculate the number of pixels that would be turned on? If the output of the plot is optional, then no one will do it.

Comment: So quadrature by the midpoint rule?

Comment: no, integrate by counting pixels on the plot, something like (blue pixels - red pixels) / (total pixels) * (xmax - xmin) * (ymax - ymin)

Comment: Ok, so it's left point rather than midpoint and quantised. What correctness constraints are there? I'm sure I could construct a test case which distinguishes different ways of looping over the x-values.

Comment: It's Monte Carlo without randomness :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lua, 219 chars**

Done it all in 1 step, no need for an intermediate table. Plots the function too ;)

```
function I(f,x,X,y,Y,r,R)I=io.write N=0 for k=R-1,0,-1 do for l=0,r-1 do v=f(x+l*(X-x)/r) K=y+k*(Y-y)/R c=(K<0 and K>v)and'-'or(K>0 and K<v and'+')or' 'N=c=="+"and N+1 or(c=="-"and N-1 or N)I(c)end I'\n'end return N end
```

Test code:

```
assert(I(math.sin,1.0,8.0,-1,1,30,15)==19)
```